# Place Div under Div as well as using Clear: both issue

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am having a few issues which my css, I am not the best at css I am more of a back-end developer so sorry if this comes across stupid.

I have a sidebar menu which looks like this:

[image: Side Menu Picture One]

I am now trying to add another menu underneath. The sidemenu container has float: left so when I add another menu it just overlaps the current one. So I researched the issue and came accross the solution which was to add clear: both to the second menu. This then cause the following issue:

[image: Side Menu Picture 2]

As you can see it has now pushed my main container down is there a way to keep this at the top?

If you need further information please ask its just hard to share css code since there is so much of it. Thank you for any help.

Also I am using bootstrap just incase this helps

Here is the my HTML and CSS code:

```
{% include 'components/dashboard/menus/sidebar.twig' %}
<div id="page-wrapper"></div>
```

The page-wrapper is the main page content which has been moved down as you can see I include the sidebar before this code. Here is the sidemenu code:

```
<!-- BEGIN SIDEBAR WRAPPER -->
<div class="page-sidebar-wrapper">
    <!-- BEGIN SIDEBAR 1 -->
    <div class="page-sidebar navbar-collapse collapse">
        <!-- BEGIN SIDEBAR MENU 1 -->
        <ul class="page-sidebar-menu" id="wifi_platform_menu" data-keep-expanded="false" data-auto-scroll="true" data-slide-speed="200">
            <div id="wifi_platform_header" style="background-color: #1c2746; height: 50px; width: 100%; cursor: pointer;" class="text-center">
                <img src="{{site.uri.public}}/images/WiFi-Logo-Image.png" height="38px" width="38px" style="margin-top: 5px"/>
                <img src="{{site.uri.public}}/images/WiFi-Logo-Text.png" height="38" width="150" style="margin-top: 7px; margin-left: 5px" class="wifi-logo-text"/>
            </div>
        </ul>
        <!-- END SIDEBAR MENU 1 -->
    </div>
    <!-- END SIDEBAR 1 -->

    <!-- BEGIN SIDEBAR 2 -->
    <div class="page-sidebar navbar-collapse collapse" style="clear: both">
        <!-- BEGIN SIDEBAR MENU 2 -->
        <ul class="page-sidebar-menu" id="geo_sense_menu" data-keep-expanded="false" data-auto-scroll="true" data-slide-speed="200">
            <div id="geo_sense_header" style="background-color: #1c2746; height: 50px; width: 100%; cursor: pointer;" class="text-center">
                <span id="wifi_platform_header_text" class="title bold" style="font-size: 25px; color: white; vertical-align: middle;">Geo Sense</span>
            </div>
        </ul>
        <!-- END SIDEBAR MENU 2 -->
    </div>
    <!-- END SIDEBAR 2 -->
</div>
<!-- END SIDEBAR WRAPPER 2 -->
```

Above is the code which is included, this displays the sidebars. The code doesn't show the list items like the image does, I took that out since it isn't needed for this example.

As you can see in the second sidemenu I added the style "clear: both" which stopped them from overlapping but also pushed the main page content down.

Here is the .page-sidebar class which is floating the menu to the left:

```
.page-sidebar {
    width: 235px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    margin-right: -100%;
}
```

So just to confirm the problem is I want the main page content to be at the top and not get pushed down.

Comment: It would be easy to help if you share link.

Comment: Its a locked down system so I cant I am afraid sorry

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: If no one is able to help without access to it I may create a locked down temp account for people to use

Comment: I have now added code to this question so you can now remove your down votes and let me know if anything else is needed

Comment: What is the CSS for id="page-wrapper" ?

Comment: @Tushar Hi mate it doesnt matter I managed to figure it out I just made ```page-sidebar-wrapper``` absolute and stopped floating the menus to the left. Could you take your downvote off now since I explained it properly

Comment: I have not downvoted the question.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using bootstrap grids?

if so:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-4">
    //menu goes here
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-8">
    //widgets goes here
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi I am afraid im not, I will try and share my code is a readable way so you can see what happening